# MySQL 5.7+ is required to use JSONField

Tags: mysql, django, django-migrations, pythonanywhere

I was initialising my django project to pythonanywhere.com but while i was migrating i saw this error.

(django_mysql.E016) MySQL 5.7+ is required to use JSONField
HINT: At least one of your DB connections should be to MySQL 5.7+

I am using JSONField in my models. Can anyone suggest me a fix?

Settings.py

```
'default' :{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '******',
        'USER': '****',
        'PASSWORD': '*****',
        'HOST': '******',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            # Tell MySQLdb to connect with 'utf8mb4' character set
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
        },
    },
```

Comment: MySQL supports JSON starting from version 5.7.8. If you need to use this datatype then your MySQL server version cannot be lower. So only MySQL server version upgrade may help you to fix your problem.

Comment: You can store JSON data in TEXT or other similar data type.  The good news is that you have your JSON data in a column but the bad news is that parsing that data from within MySQL gets tricky.  I suggest that you use a JSON data type to be able to take advantage of the JSON functions MySQL provides.

Comment: If you drop a line to PythonAnywhere tech support (support@pythonanywhere.com) they will be able to move your account's database over to a server running MySQL 5.7.

Comment: `JSONField is supported on MariaDB 10.2.7+, MySQL 5.7.8+, Oracle, PostgreSQL, and SQLite 3.9.0+ (with the JSON1 extension enabled)`. Details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField